# Changing className vs Changing innerHTML

Tags: css, innerhtml, classname

I need to toggle two words (i.e Hello & World).  Now I have created two `span`s and using CSS I am toggling them.  However I can create a single `div` and change the innerHTML alone.  My question is which one is valid and efficient?  Below is sample HTML, CSS, JS code.

```html
<div class='enablecss2'>
    <span class='css1'>Hello</span>
    <span class='css2'>World</span>
</div>

.css2 {
    display:none;
}

.enablecss2 .css2 {
    display:block;
}

.enablecss2 .css1 {
    display:none;
}

<script>
    function toggle(el,event)
      { 
          if(el.className == '')
              el.className = 'enablecss2';
          else
              el.className = '';
      }

</script>
```

Comment: or option C which would be to use .textContent and not muck about with the two elements or innerHTML

Comment: If you set `el.className = 'enablecss2'`, it will overwrite the class value of the attribute, so it ceases to contain 'css1'.

Comment: Considering accessibility and assistive technologies, method A might be a better choice since you have both words in the markup and in the end the user is supposed to see the entire content (both words).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are valid methods, and in terms of rendering speed of the toggle it doesn't matter. But in terms of efficient coding (= less code with the same result), the `innerHTML` method is the better method, because you need less HTML and no CSS code for that:

```
<div class='enablecss2'>
    Hello
</div>

<script>
// your toggle function
</script>
```

Comment: If the downvoter would have the decency to give the reason for it?